# How to filter the same elements from two sources

Tags: scala, akka-stream

There are two sources:

```
val s1 = Source(List(2, 4))
val s2 = Source(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

How to filter elements from `s2` which are existed in `s1`. For above example it will be:

```
val s2Filtered = Source(List(1, 3, 5))
```

Another use case:

```
val s1 = Source(List.empty[Int])
val s2 = Source(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
val s2Filtered = Source(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) // because s1 is empty
```

Comment: What kind of problems did you encounter when you tried to implement this?

Comment: Are the sources always sorted, as in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a very good use case for streaming, as you are going to need to fully exhaust the first stream into memory to be able to perform this operation.
Just be aware the first stream will need to fit into memory to be able to proceed.

Here's a way to do it

```
  for{
    set  ← s1.runFold(Set.empty[Int]){case (set, n) ⇒ set + n}
    done ← s2.filter(set.contains).runForeach(println)
  } yield done
```